# Reduce the length of underscore inside detokenize

Tags: fonts, underline, underscore, detokenize

Like [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128814/decrease-length-of-underscore-character-in-normal-text-gender-gap)

But because many of my keywords has underscore, I created a macro called \keyword with \detokenize to make things easy. However, it makes underscore become longer again.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\NewDocumentCommand\keyword{sm}{\emph{\detokenize{#2}}}
\renewcommand{\_}{\textscale{.6}{\textunderscore}}

\begin{document}

This method works for:\\
    \verb|\emph{\_\_all\_\_}|\quad\textrightarrow\quad \emph{\_\_all\_\_}\\
\par
But not works for:\\
    \verb|\keyword{__all__}|\quad\textrightarrow\quad \keyword{__all__}\\

Maybe the reason is the same as this one:\\
    \verb|\char`_\char`_all\char`_\char`_|\quad\textrightarrow\quad \char`_\char`_all\char`_\char`_\\

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I am wondering, why you are trying to reinvent the wheel. If you want to typeset code use `\verb` or `\lstinline` and adjust the style (font, color, etc.) instead of implementing the commands yourself

Comment: This is another style and I prefer it using `\emph` instead of typewrite font

Comment: And `\lstinline[language=,basicstyle=\itshape]{__all__}` also has a lone underline

Comment: if you use `\_` and define it to be a rule, you can ask tex to draw any length you wish. If you use detokenize (or  `\verb` `\char` (or the latex version `\symbol`) etc  then you are typesetting the character from the font, and asking for a different length is like asking for a narrower `M` not necessarily impossible but a question of font design, not TeX.

Comment: I see, really impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup `listings` to format the code the way you want. The option `literate` allows you to replace characters on the fly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\itshape,
  literate={_}{\textscale{.6}{\textunderscore}}1
}

\renewcommand{\_}{\textscale{.6}{\textunderscore}}

\begin{document}

  \verb|\emph{\_\_all\_\_}|\quad\textrightarrow\quad \emph{\_\_all\_\_}

  \verb|\lstinline{__all__}|\quad\textrightarrow\quad \lstinline{__all__}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `fontenc` missing? Furthermore I would maybe add a small space around the literate substitution of `_` as to make clear that there are two underscores.

Comment: @campa I seperate them by adding a small space `\kern0.1em`

Answer (score 2):

listings processes the input, and you can redefine the output you get for an input. Replace the xx/yy with whatever you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\itshape,
}

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"5F}{%
      \lst@ttfamily
         {xx}% used with ttfamily
         {yy}}% used with other fonts
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother 


\begin{document}

  \lstinline{__all__}
  \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{__all__}

\end{document}
```

[image]